# objct Timestamp not found when sort_by

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
Timestamp    Value   Name
10/09/17     15       A
10/09/17     1000     A   
11/09/17     15       B
11/09/17     1000     B
....
```

I want to find out which Names contain the value 1000 at which timestamps.

I tried:

```
tdata <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(value == 1000)
```

which works, but when I try to sort by Timestamp:

```
 tdata <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(value == 1000) %>% sort_by(Timestamp)
```

it shows `Error in as)_function(.f, ...) :object 'Timestamp' not found`

Comment: Do you need `arrange` ? `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(Value == 1000) %>% arrange(Timestamp)` ? or you can use `desc` to sort it in descending order.

Comment: what is `sort_by`?. I never seen that function before

Comment: @RonakShah:Yes!I wanted arrange as I can see, thanks.Please, make it an answer

Comment: @Sotos:I just wanted to sort by timestamp, but arrange is doing the job.